# cout a string from class outputs a "nan"

Tags: c++, class, object, console-application

I created a class that holds the information about a character in a game. I also created a constructor for it. But when I cout a string or a float from the class, it outputs a "nan" or a weird and long number or just nothing.
look at the code:-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

class Character {
public:
    string type;
    string name;
    float HP;
    float MP;
    float str;
    float def;
    float agility;
    int LVL;

    Character(string atype, string aname, float aHP, float aMP, float astr, float adef, float aagility, int aLVL){
        string type = atype;
        string name = aname;
        float HP = aHP;
        float MP = aMP;
        float str = astr;
        float def = adef;
        float agility = aagility;
        int LVL = aLVL;
    }
};

int main()
{

    Character war("Warrior", "Achilles",    100, 30,  50,  35,    30,     1);

    cout << war.type << endl;
    cout << war.name << endl;
    cout << war.HP << endl;
    cout << war.MP << endl;
    cout << war.str << endl;
    cout << war.def << endl;
    cout << war.agility << endl;
    cout << war.LVL << endl;
    cout << "Test String" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and the output is:-

```
//nothing
//nothing again
1.08418e-038
1.08418e-038
4.15749e+033
4.19234e-033
nan
36
Test String
```

Please help!

Comment: Your `Character` does not assign any member, only local temps (which shadow the members).

Comment: You're constructor is not setting your object's members but instead local variables. Take care that there's a difference between `string type = atype;` and `type = atype;` and so forth.

Comment: A side note: better to avoid `using namespace std` - see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice.

Comment: Turn some warnings on!

Comment: But `war.agility` is not a string, it is a `float`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Character(string atype, string aname, float aHP, float aMP, float astr, float adef, float aagility, int aLVL){
    string type = atype;
    string name = aname;
    float HP = aHP;
    float MP = aMP;
    float str = astr;
    float def = adef;
    float agility = aagility;
    int LVL = aLVL;
}
```

should be

```
Character(string atype, string aname, float aHP, float aMP, float astr, float adef, float aagility, int aLVL){
    type = atype;
    name = aname;
    HP = aHP;
    MP = aMP;
    str = astr;
    def = adef;
    agility = aagility;
    LVL = aLVL;
}
```

Your version creates new variables which **hide the class members** you are trying to assign to! That's why they have garbage values.

The preferred way to do this however is to use an *initialiser list*

```
Character(string atype, string aname, float aHP, float aMP, float astr, float adef, float aagility, int aLVL)
    : type(atype)
    , name(aname)
    , HP(aHP)
    , MP(aMP)
    , str(astr)
    , def(adef)
    , agility(aagility)
    , LVL(aLVL)
{
}
```

Comment: Or, even better, `: type(atype), name(aname), ...`. Then you don't even need `a` as prefix.

Comment: I am not sure about an initialiser list being the "_proper_" way though.  The _preferred_ way perhaps?

Comment: @Clifford Fair enough.